# combine surface texture(external basically camera feed ) and ordinary texture

Tags: android, android-camera, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

i am trying to combine surface texture(external basically camera feed ) and ordinary texture , when i run this the screen becomes black i tried in galaxy s5,s6 got the same results,searched online but couldn't find any resources for this,Any feedback is welcome.

shaders

```
private final String vertexShaderCodeCamera ="uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
        "attribute vec4 position;" +
                "attribute vec2 inputTextureCoordinate;" +
                "varying vec2 textureCoordinate;" +
                "attribute vec3 a_normal;"+ //new line
                "varying vec3 v_normal;"+//new line
                "uniform mat4 u_MVMatrix;" +
                "void main()" +
                "{" +
                " gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * position;" +
                "textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate;" +
                "v_normal = vec3(u_MVMatrix * vec4(a_normal, 0.0));"+

                "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCodeCamera =
                "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
                "precision mediump float;" +
                "varying vec2 textureCoordinate;                            \n" +
                "uniform samplerExternalOES s_texture;               \n" +
                "uniform sampler2D Texture;" +
                "void main(void) {" +
                "gl_FragColor = texture2D(s_texture, textureCoordinate );\n" +
                "gl_FragColor = texture2D(Texture, textureCoordinate);" +
                 "}";
```

camera draw method:

```
public void display_Camera(int texture){
    GLES20.glUseProgram(cam_mProgram);

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, texture);


    cam_mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(cam_mProgram, "position");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(cam_mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(cam_mPositionHandle, CAM_COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStrideSquare, vertexBuffer);


    cam_mTextureCoordHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(cam_mProgram, "inputTextureCoordinate");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(cam_mTextureCoordHandle);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(cam_mTextureCoordHandle, CAM_COORDS_PER_VERTEX, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStrideSquare, textureVerticesBuffer);

    cam_mColorHandle = 2;//GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(cam_mProgram, "s_texture");


    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);


    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(cam_mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(cam_mTextureCoordHandle);

}
```

model draw method:

```
public void draw1(float[] mvpMatrix) {
    // Add program to OpenGL environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(cam_mProgram);

    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mPositionHandle = 0;//GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(cam_mProgram, "vPosition");
    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(cam_mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    MainActivity.checkGLError("glGetUniformLocation");


    fsTexture = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(cam_mProgram, "Texture");
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(fsTexture, 0);
    vsTextureCoord = 1;//GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(cam_mProgram, "texCoord");

    mNormalHandle = 3;//GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(cam_mProgram, "a_normal");//new line

    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
            mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vsTextureCoord, COORDS_PER_TEXTURE,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            TextureStride, texBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vsTextureCoord);

    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mNormalHandle, COORDS_PER_NORMAL, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            12, normalbuffer);//new line

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mNormalHandle);//new line
    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    MainActivity.checkGLError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

    // Draw the triangle
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, tablelamp21NumVerts);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(vsTextureCoord);
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mNormalHandle);
}
```

linking of shaders:

```
cam_mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL Program
    if (cam_mProgram != 0)
    {
        // Bind the vertex shader to the program.
        GLES20.glAttachShader(cam_mProgram, cameravertexShader);

        // Bind the fragment shader to the program.
        GLES20.glAttachShader(cam_mProgram, camerafragmentShader);

        // Bind attributes
        GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(cam_mProgram, 0, "position");
        GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(cam_mProgram, 1, "inputTextureCoordinate");
        GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(cam_mProgram, 2, "s_texture");//new line
        GLES20.glBindAttribLocation(cam_mProgram, 3, "a_normal");//new line

        // Link the two shaders together into a program.
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(cam_mProgram);

        // Get the link status.
        final int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetProgramiv(cam_mProgram, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);

        // If the link failed, delete the program.
        if (linkStatus[0] == 0)
        {
            GLES20.glDeleteProgram(cam_mProgram);
            cam_mProgram = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're assigning `gl_FragColor` twice, rather than assigning it once from a blending operation. You've got two different draw methods that presumably overwrite each other. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @fadden -My goal is to mix the output of both texture2D into one as one is of camera texture (i am converting the frames from camera hardware into texture to display them in the view) and the other one is a texture of 3D model. I want the camera to always be running in the background and augment the 3D model to it.so for that i used two draw and gl_FragColor one for camera texture and one for model ,which i am unable to do any help would be appreciated. i am trying to do something like this   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_reality#/media/File:AR_EdiBear0001390_1.jpg

Comment: If you just want one in front of the other, draw them as two separate operations. You can put the geometry for the 3D model at a Z offset in front of the background, or turn off the depth buffer and just draw the background first. Use alpha blending on the model if you want it to be partially transparent. You don't need to sample both textures from a single shader unless you want to combine the pixels in some unusual way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it worked ,but it doesn't look like it is augmented to the environment  but it looks as one in front of other as u said, i want to render the model according to the environment i.e position and camera angle etc.. i searched online most of them were suggesting vuforia but most of its documentation is for cardboard with unity not opengles ,so if u know any other sdk let me know